# Al hacer una consulta en SQL donde toma información de un archivo .CSV que esta en un servidor, no me respeta las decimales del archivo

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta.

```
select *    
from openrowset ('msdasql', 'driver={microsoft text driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; 
defaultdir=f:\Temp\Presupuesto\Formatos Gasto\;' 
,'select * from menores.csv')
```

Esto hace que obtenga la información de un archivo que esta en un servidor, el problema es que cuando realizo la consulta me muestra la información de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo esperado seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si voy al archivo .CSV que esta dentro del servidor se muestran las cantidades por decimales, pero si yo realizo la consulta no las respeta.

Comment: Puedes poner el contenido del archivo como texto?

Comment: Claro, Cuenta, Descripcion, Empresa, Cliente, 5108010101, Directos, 129902.23, 22345.12, 5108010103, administracion de fideicomisos, 345567.65, 11232.4